# Тип serial инкрементируется без вставки записи в таблицу

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, pgadmin4

В таблице есть несколько полей. Одно из них типа serial. Другое поле character varying с длиной 10. Остальные не имеют ограничений. Когда я пытаюсь вставить в таблицу запись, у которой поле с типом character varying превышает заданную длину, pgadmin4 выдаёт мне ошибку и не вставляет эту запись. Но следующая запись которая вставится в табличку,будет иметь значение поля с типом serial = последнее число + количество неудачных вставок. Разве так и должно работать?

Comment: Да, так и должно работать. Представьте, что запросы на вставку идут из разных потоков/процессов одновременно. Если по какой-либо причине одна из вставок не получится, это не должно повлиять на остальные.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Хм, как по мне это немного странно. Я так понимаю ,что бы этого не было придётся писать свой обработчик?

Comment: Айдишники не предназначены для вас, не предназначены для человека, не предназначены для красоты. А для машины совершенно неважно, идут ли они с пропусками или без. Поэтому, пожалуйста, не лезьте туда, где ваша "помощь" не нужна. Оставьте генерацию последовательностей в покое.